# Javascript: Looping through the characters of elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, character

I have the following problem:

Write a function that takes in a list of words, and returns an object that tells you how many times each letter showed up.

So something like this:

```
var data = ['hat', 'cat', 'dog'];
```

becomes:

```
var object = {
  'a' : 2,
  'h' : 1,
  't' : 2,
  'c' : 2,
  'd' : 1,
  'g' : 1
};
```

My solution thus far has been to:

1. Create a function with a blank object.
2. Loop through all the elements of the array

These steps aren't working like I think they were:

3. Try to loop through the characters of each array element.
4. If the character of the array element is undefined in the object, put it in and increment to one. Otherwise if its already there, increment it by one again.

Where am I going wrong? Or am I way off?

Comment: "*Where am I going wrong*" - you "forgot" to read [ask]

Comment: add your code please

Comment: `join` the array into a string so you don't have to use two loops.

Comment: What Andy is suggesting is the best solution.  Just put all of your array values into a string and then parse the string for individual character counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are searching for:

```js
// Function that you need.
function letterUsage(data) {
    // Collector.
    var result = {};
    
    // Loop.
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
            var letter = data[i][j];
            if (result[letter]) {
                result[letter] = result[letter] + 1;
            } else {
                result[letter] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// Prepare test.
var data = ['hat', 'cat', 'dog'];
var result = letterUsage(data);

// Print result.
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Exactly how I wanted to do it. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one [`Reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) just first `join` array to one string and then `split` it on each letter

```js
var data = ['hat', 'cat', 'dog'];

data = data.join('').split('').reduce(function(sum, el) {
  sum[el] = (sum[el] || 0) + 1;
  return sum;
}, {});

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) alternative:

```js
var data = ['hat', 'cat', 'dog'];

var object = {};

data.join('').split('').forEach(letter => { object[letter] = ++object[letter] || 1;});

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```